# Distinct function with same integration over same interval

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible that 2 different functions to have the same definite integral over same interval?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it quite possible to have different functions with the same definite integrals. Consider $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 2x/3$ on the interval $[0 , 1]$. Both integrals have the same value of $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be any integrable function, and $h(x)=f(x)+\sin(x)\,$, then $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} h(x) dx\,$.

More generally, if $f, g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b g(x) dx = 0\,$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b h(x) dx$ where $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)\,$.